# Mod redirect in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I want to use mod_rewrite in cakephp. when user type domain name user should redirect to http://domain.com/index.html.

Comment: You probably mean `mod_rewrite`. Anyway, good idea! Makes for much nicer URLs.

Comment: mod_redirect? Don’t you mean mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your CakePHP location:

If it runs inside a directory that is a child of the webserver's root directory (accessed as http://domain.com/cakephp) you can just use this:

In the default action of your default controller put this:

```
$this->redirect('http://domain.com/index.html')
```

Otherwise if CakePHP is running from the root of the server (accessed as http://domain.com)  just but index.html inside webroot and you dont need to do anything in code.

Hope that will help.